# What is the relation between inner product defined on subgroup of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and similarity?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $G$ be a bounded subgroup of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. An inner product defined on the closure of $G$ (by a special way for example integral and Haar measure or another way, no matter). Next, it is proved that every $S$ in closure of $G$ is unitary (In fact, it is proved $S$ is isometry with respect to the inner product).

Now, it is claimed that every matrix $G$ is simultaneously similar to a group of unitary matrices.

Why is it claimed? What is the relation between inner product defined on subgroup of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and similarity?